# How to add Listmodes in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.3, product-list

How to add the list modes in magento 2 custom module. I need list modes like below image.
http://prntscr.com/mwrq23

and my productlist.phtml file is

```
<div class="container-list container">
    <div class="page-title">
        <!--<h1 class="page-title">Search Products A-Z</h1>-->
        <h1>Products A-Z</h1>
        <h2 class="product-list">A to Z List of Formulas that Set the Standard for Quality</h2>
    </div>
    <p class="list-content">We strive to make exceptional nutritional supplements to meet your health goals. That's why we follow standards for quality, purity, safety and effectiveness that far exceed that of our competitors. For product details, browse this easy-to-use&nbsp;alphabetical list.</p>


    <?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
//$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
    $abstractProductBlock = $block->getLayout()->createBlock('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct');
    $listBlock = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct');
//$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    $collection = $block->getProductCollection();
    //echo "<pre>";print_r($collection->getData());die("here");
    $_collectionSize = count($collection);
    $_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount();
    $helperImport = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
    ?>
    <div class="custom-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?php echo $block->getPagerHtml(); ?></div>
    <?= $block->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('my_product_list_toolbar');?>
    <div class="custom-products-grid products-grid--max-<?php echo $_columnCount; ?>-col">
        <?php if (!$collection->count()): ?>
            <p class="note-msg"><?php echo 'There are no products matching the selection.' ?></p>
            <?php
        else:
            $i = 0;
            $j = 0;
            $total = count($collection);
            foreach ($collection as $_product):
                $i++;
                $j++;

                $imageUrl = $helperImport->init($_product, 'product_page_image_small')
                        ->setImageFile($_product->getSmallImage()) // image,small_image,thumbnail
                        ->resize(380)
                        ->getUrl();
                ?>
                <div class="col-sm-4 no-lrp<?php if ($i == 2) echo ' lr-border'; ?><?php if ($i == 1) echo ' l-border'; ?><?php if ($i == 3) echo ' r-border'; ?><?php if ($j == $total) echo ' last'; ?>">
                    <div class="image-blck">
                        <div class="image">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>" class="product-image">                      
                                <?php $_imgSize = 88; ?>
                                <img height="88" width="88" id="product-collection-image-<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>" src="<?php echo $imageUrl; ?>" alt="<?php echo $_product->getName(); ?>" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-info">
                        <p class="product-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>" title="<?php $_product->getName(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>
                        </p>
                        <div class="price"><?php echo $abstractProductBlock->getProductPrice($_product); ?></div>
                        <ul class="add-to-links">
                            <?php if ($_product->getTypeId() != "configurable") : ?>
                                <li><a href="<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Wishlist\Helper\Data')->getAddParams($_product); ?>" class="link-wishlist"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to List')); ?></span></a></li>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </ul>
                        <?php $addToCartUrl = $listBlock->getAddToCartUrl($_product); ?>
                        <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && ($_product->getTypeId() != "configurable")): ?>
                            <p class="action"><button type="button" title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $objectManager->get('Magento\Checkout\Helper\Cart')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span></button></p>
                        <?php elseif ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                            <p class="action"><a title="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('View Details')) ?>" class="button" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('View Details')) ?></a></p>
                        <?php else: ?>
                            <p class="action availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span></p>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
            endforeach;
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin configuration:

> Store -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog

select mode from **List Mode**
[image]

Comment: In custom module how can i add this list modes?

Comment: Do you want both options to show on custom module or you want just one to select by default?

Comment: I need both grid and list views mode,but By default select grid mode.please help on this

Comment: your need to share your code where you are calling list.phtml file, then I can tell what to do with it

Comment: productlist_index_index.xml its my layout file
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Custom\Productlist\Block\Index" name="custom_productlist" template="Custom_Productlist::productlist.phtml">
     <block class="Custom\Productlist\Block\Toolbar" name="my_product_list_toolbar" template="Custom_Productlist::list/toolbar.phtml"/>
 </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>

Comment: updated my question with my .phtml and added comment for layout file

Answer (score 0):

You just implement grid and list view based template like product listing page. Refer below file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml`. And use `javascript` stuff to change list from grid and vice versa.